# Render html using csv data rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following csv file `data.csv`:

```
id,name,description
1,John Doe,Lorem ipsum
```

I want to render this into HTML, something like:

```
<%= data.name + ": " + data.description %>
```

How can I do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the ruby library CSV: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html.

You can do something along the lines this in your controller:

```
@rows = CSV.read('path_to_file/data.csv', headers: true)
```

And then look through the rows in your partial and output the data based on your header in the file:

```
data.each do |row|
<%= "#{row['name']}: #{row['description']}" %>
end
```